# No response data from GeoServer when using EPSG::4326 projection

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, geowebcache, mbtiles, configuration

So I have a Zurich vector (.mbtile) data set I would like to render in a browser using GeoServer.  I was able to use geocache to serve the data in the EPSG::900913 projection using the following source endpoint:

```
http://ww.xxx.yyy.zzz:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=cite:building&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}
```

When I re-configured the GeoServer layer for EPSG::4326, it returns 200 when hitting the tiles in Geocache, but no actual response data shows up.  The native projection of the .mbtile file is EPSG::3857, and I am force-declaring it to EPSG::4326.  Both bounding boxes are -180 -90 180 90, and I deleted the associated gridsets for the layer and re-added only EPSG::4326.

But still, no joy.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo , but the URL above is missing a `?`, `wmtsREQUEST` should be `wmts?REQUEST`

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: nmtoken, you were correct.  I fixed the typo in my question -- the '?' is present in my actual code.